# ASP.NET Menu Control - get selected item after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my master page (let's name it `MasterPage1`) I have the menu control

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
   <Items>
       <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/" Text="tab1"></asp:MenuItem>
       <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx" Text="tab2"></asp:MenuItem>
       <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx" Text="tab3"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

`page1.aspx` has the same master page `MasterPage1`. If I click on the `tab2` and `tab3` I must know which one was selected

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get Menu control reference from master page
    //get selected item
}
```

but I see always the `tab1` is selected. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you add a query string?  i.e. `NavigateUrl="~/page1.asp?tab=2"`

Comment: Yeah, query string will work, or if you don't want the user to see which tab they selected / change it manually you could store it in Session Memory

Comment: I could, but I don't want (I really don't like the query strings)

Comment: use the `OnMenuItemClick` event?

Comment: @MikeyMouse but what if user opens many browser tabs ? Then the Session approach fails

Comment: @Tony are you using this menu for navigation or just to run some logic within the same page?

Answer (score 2):

You could not store the information in session/viewstate/hidden when you navigate using `<a href="url">` created by ASP.Net menu, since it issues a fresh `GET` request and loads the page.

Append the  Query string in url like `NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx?selected=tab1"`

Comment: `Session` would be available.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel, how come you store the value in session when you click `<a>`. It is a link basically. How you write a server code when navigation is happening?

Comment: yes, very true. I read your answer as Session objects would not be available upon a refresh. You are right that you would not be able to set any value using a hyperlink. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Just use MenuItemClick Event to get current item clicked and try to store it into a Session and use after redirection. for more information visit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

ADD this to page load event of pages opened by redirect.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Menu Menu = (Menu)Page.Master.FindControl("Menu1");
        if (Menu.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (MenuItem mi in Menu.Items)
            {
                if (mi.Text == "Contact Us")
                {
                    mi.Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```